# Javascript not executing in a response page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I have an issue when I get a page response from the server after a Post submit

This is my html code:

```
<form id="form" action="someaction" method="post">
   <input name="somedata" id="somedata" />
</form>
```

Then I have this script

```
document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

The script submits the form just fine and then the page 'someaction' is loaded correctly, the problem is, I have a jQuery script on the response page, and I want that script to execute when the new page finishes loading, however that never happens, I tried $(document).ready() and pageLoad() but neither one of them works.

Is there any solution available?

Edit:

The code on the new page is the next, I'm trying to debug this with Chrome's console, but when I open the sources, no javascript is shown, but If I inspect the page, the javascript with the tags is there.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Response from server</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="newForm">
       <input name="newInput" />
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
         $("input").click(function () {
           alert("attached");
         });
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the input it doesn't trigger the alert.

Comment: What's the code on the new page?

Comment: Post the exact code that doesn't word

Comment: There's always a solution, but we need to see the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the problem isn't with the code you posted, since it's a different page that loads.